# InputStream using read and read(bytearray)

Tags: java, inputstream

Why the read () method is different in reading the total number of byte? 
For example,

```
int n = System.in.read();
System.out.println("The total bytes are:"+System.in.available());
```

And in another place we use

```
byte [] in= new byte[30]; 
int n = System.in.read(byte);
System.out.println("The total bytes are:"+System.in.available());
```

And the word **Java** has been read in both methods

The output of the first method is :

```
the total bytes are 5
```

Where the second method is:

```
 the total bytes are 6
```

What is the differnce in returing bytes between these two methods?

Comment: your 2nd code snippet is not compiling, edit your question

Comment: The number of bytes available to be read without blocking from System.in depends entirely on how far you have typed ahead.

Answer (score 1):

As the Javadoc says of the available() method, it: "Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream ***without blocking*** by the next invocation of a method for this input stream."

The exact way a stream determines this count is not strictly defined. In the case of System.in it may use the number of bytes currently available in its internal buffer, or it may delegate the call to the underlying input stream which may be implementation dependent (e.g. by operating system). The only thing you can really determine from the returned value is the number of bytes you should be able to safely read without blocking.

Comment: BarrySW19, your comments are highly appreciated and also i have read Javadoc . Actually, the problem is related with the huge data from the internal buffer. This will cause confuse in many cases by using these two methods.

Comment: @MehdiAcademic2014 Actually you are just guessing as to the mere existence of 'huge dat from the internal buffer', let alone its effect on this problem if any.

Answer (score 0):

`System.in.read()` it read value from standard input stream.

```
byte [] in= new byte[30]; 
int n = System.in.read(byte);
```

- It reads value from your in array.

Comment: atish, your comments are correct but why the first one return 5 bytes and the other return 6 bytes. I know the first printout 5 bytes betcause it takes the CR but what about the read(bytes) which returns 6 bytes.

Comment: Neither is returning the number of read bytes - the method returns the minimum number of bytes still available to read.

Comment: @BarrySW19 The read() method returns the number of bytes it read. The available() method returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking. *Neither* of them returns 'the minimum number of bytes still available to read'.

Comment: I'm not sure why you see a difference between "the number of bytes that can be read without blocking" and the "minimum number of bytes still available to read". They clearly mean the same thing.